# Getting ORA-01036 error when using output parameter in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I am having a problem with an Output parameter in C#/Oracle. I have isolated the code that I need to get working.

This is part of a much larger SQL statement, so do not worry too much if it doesn't make sense. In short I need to copy a row, give it a new ID and return that new ID. I tried using "RETURNING" which did not work. I see no reason why the code below should not work, but I'm getting an "ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number" error. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```cs
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
{
    // Open connection and create command.
    conn.Open();
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("outValue", OracleType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT seq.nextval INTO :outValue FROM dual";
         try
         {
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             // This is just to see the exception when it fails.
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: "c#" doesn't give that error... an oracle library, or the oracle server gives that error...

Comment: Yes, obviously it is the Oracle Library giving me the error. I write it like that because the SQL statement works fine in PL/SQL.

Comment: Changed the title to avoid misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the parameter doesn't match.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(":outValue", OracleType.Int32).Direction.......;
                    ^
```

I have also seen this variation on the query syntax

```
"BEGIN SELECT seq.nextval INTO :outValue FROM dual END;"
```

Comment: With most ADO.NET providers, you don't need to include that. I would be amazed if this was different for OracleCommand

Comment: @MarcGravell Strange, I have always used that prefix on 'in-line' query. I did not know that

Comment: Yes! Using BEGIN and END did the trick.
"BEGIN SELECT seq.nextval INTO :outValue FROM dual; END;"

Answer (score 0):

You are using named parameters. Try setting:

```
cmd.BindByName = true;
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen this in another post but I do not have property on my command variable.
It should probably be noted that I'm using System.Data.OracleClient;
It's a ClickOnce application so I cannot use Oracles own library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 'returning' keyword like this?
This code works for me.

```
 using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connString))
 {
     // Open connection and create command.
     conn.Open();
     using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand())
     {
         cmd.Connection = conn;
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         cmd.Parameters.Add("outValue", OracleType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
         cmd.CommandText = "insert into table (id, value) values (seq.nextval, 'value') returning id into :outValue";
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes the RETURNING keyword would work, but I can't use in the complete query. I needed to do something like this:

`INSERT INTO table (id, text)
SELECT seq.nextval, text 
FROM table WHERE id = :id
RETURNING id INTO :outValue`

The query without the RETURNING keyword works and copies the row, but when you add RETURNING it produces a "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error.